# Jgit: Jgitinternalexception:Missing tree XXXXXXXX

Tags: java, jgit

How to resolve this error in? I tried to debug in my own pc, and it's worked with no Exception; but error happens in linux service!
I used Jgit API to parse diff, but when executed to the debug line, exception happens: [this pic shows the code as below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhr67.png)

```
ObjectId baseObjId = oldGit.getRepository().resolve(coverageReport.getBaseVersion()); 
ObjectId nowObjId = newGit.getRepository().resolve(coverageReport.getNowVersion());            
AbstractTreeIterator newTree = prepareTreeParser(newRepository, nowObjId);
AbstractTreeIterator oldTree = prepareTreeParser(oldRepository, baseObjId);
List<DiffEntry> diff = newGit.diff().setOldTree(oldTree).setNewTree(newTree).setShowNameAndStatusOnly(true).call();
```

[this pic shows the objectID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDTT1.png)

[this pic is the error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaIq9.png)

Comment: is there any pre-condition?  Besides:  BaseVersion = master ; NowVersion = feature branch;

Comment: Below is the stack msg
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.MissingObjectException: Missing tree 43c70444fdbac531be50c16c94bd95eb0804cffe
 at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.WindowCursor.open(WindowCursor.java:164)
 at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.CanonicalTreeParser.reset(CanonicalTreeParser.java:214)